# How save a native variable with streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Hi im trying to understand java 8 api streams, i dont know if this can be done, but im trying to do a filter to a list a save in a new variable like this and  the compiler say to me that he cant convert from Stream to String and it has sense but how can i  do the operation?

```
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    lista.add("1");
    lista.add("2");
    
    String num = lista.stream().filter(x -> x.equals("1"));
```

And if i want to convert that string to int i try to do this but also the compiler say to me, wrong types

```
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    lista.add("1");
    lista.add("2");
    
    int num = lista.stream().filter(x -> x.equals("1")).map(x -> Integer.parseInt(x));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streams don't start processing until a terminal method is given to start it. So try this:

```
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    lista.add("1");
    lista.add("2");
    
    int num = lista.stream().filter(x -> x.equals("1"))
             .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)  // use method reference here.
             .findFirst().orElse(0);
```

`findFirst` returns an `OptionalInt` so you need to have a default value to return if nothing is found.  `orElse` does that. Also use `mapToInt` since `Integer::parseInt` returns an `int`.  Avoids unnecessary boxing.  You can apply a similar technique to just get the String when you don't need to parse an int.

Comment: But it’s a convoluted way to get the same result as `int num = lista.contains("1")? 1: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing just one call to `findFirst`:

```
String num = lista.stream().filter(x -> x.equals("1")).findFirst().get();
```

And also for the `Map`:

```
int num = lista.stream().filter(x -> x.equals("1")).map(x -> Integer.parseInt(x)).findFirst().get();
```

Be careful when using `get` method of `Optional`, if the filter returns nothing it will throw `NoSuchElementException`.